# Did they figure out what caused the "high-pitched scratching noise" that Perseverance recorded with its microphone? Was it static discharge?

Tags: mars, perseverance, sound

In NASA's SoundCloud account there is [Sounds of Perseverance Mars Rover Driving – Sol 16 (16 minutes)](https://soundcloud.com/nasa/sounds-of-perseverance-mars-rover-driving-sol-16-16-minutes?in=nasa/sets/sounds-from-mars) (for example between `01:30` and `03:00` or between `12:00` and `12:15` ) and the notes say:

> Listen to 16 minutes of raw, unfiltered sounds of the Perseverance Mars rover traveling in Jezero Crater. The noise generated by the interaction of the rover’s wheels and suspension with the surface can be heard, **along with a high-pitched scratching noise. Perseverance’s engineering team continues to evaluate the source of the scratching noise, which may either be electromagnetic interference from one of the rover’s electronics boxes or interactions between the rover mobility system and the Martian surface.** The entry, descent, and landing microphone was not intended for surface operations and had limited testing in this configuration before launch.
>
> Credit: NASA/JPL-Caltech

I can't find a date, but it says "2 months ago".

To me it sounds like an electrical (rather than acoustical) pickup of static discharge (having some experience with 1970's electronics and microphone cables of that era).

Here are some acoustical(?) recordings of static discharge on Earth. They're not the same of course but I perceive some similarity.

- [The Sights and Sounds of Storm Static Electricity || ViralHog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntJ49lMxP4A) (especially after `04:00`)
- [Hikers Capture Loud Static Energy On Mountain Peak](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSKa3rkGu3M)
- [Static electricity on Table Mountain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMXK1KCJnLA)

**Question:** Did they figure out what caused the "high-pitched scratching noise" that Perseverance recorded with its microphone? Was it electrical pickup of static discharge?

Comment: Unlikely - [NASA.gov](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/another-first-perseverance-captures-the-sounds-of-driving-on-mars): "Perseverance’s engineering team continues to evaluate the source of the scratching noise, which may either be electromagnetic interference from one of the rover’s electronics boxes or interactions between the mobility system and the Martian surface. The EDL microphone was not intended for surface operations and had limited testing in this configuration before launch."

Comment: @DialFrost that's 1.5 years old; NASA rarely lets mysteries remain so.